# Avatar image flickering in VKUI component library on each re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, rerender

I’m working with JavaScript and React, using the VKUI component library. I’ve encountered an issue where the images inside the Avatar component flicker on each re-render of the component.
Here’s the custom component I’m using:

```
const Profile = ({ bingo }) => {
  return (<Div>
    <RichCell
      disabled
      before={<Avatar
        size={48}
        src={bingo.cr_ava}
      />}
      caption={bingo.cr_name}
      after={bingo.isHidden && 'Visibility limited' }
      afterCaption={bingo.isHidden && 'Hidden from feed' }
    >
      {bingo.title}
    </RichCell>
  </Div>)
}
```

This component is used in each item of a certain feed. The user’s avatar flickers.

I’ve tried to use a simple image and refrained from using the react-window library to reduce the number of re-renders. The flickering has decreased slightly, but it hasn’t disappeared.
Any ideas on why this is happening and how to fix it?